# My search query not working when i get value from label with ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

My search query not working when i get variable data from javascript here is code .It is not showing me any record. When i use break point i get  (GetScreenshot value="") it not give the that value which he contain when i run the page.actually it has value.any help

```
       <asp:Label ID="GetScreenshot" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
       <script>
           $(document).ready(function () {

         document.getElementById("GetScreenshot").innerText = localStorage.getItem("Value");
       
            });
             </script>

         **The asp.net code is** 

         private int BindList(int PageNo)
         {
         

            int TotalRows = 0;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Image FROM [ezitaske_db].[tasker_usr]. 
            [Screenshot] where Task='"+GetScreenshot.Text+"'");
           
            cmd.Connection = con;
        

           try
           {
            con.Open();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
            DataList1.DataSource = dt;
            DataList1.DataBind();
            //TotalRows = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@TotalRows"].Value);
            }
             catch (Exception ex)
            {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
            con.Close();
            sda.Dispose();
            con.Dispose();
            }
       
            return TotalRows;
       

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the code you've provided:

Your JavaScript code is executed when the page loads. `BindList` is executed when you've received a request, when you're preparing the response. As a result, there's no value in the `GetScreenShot` control for your `BindList` method to work with, because `$.document.ready()` hasn't executed.

The problem here is understanding the order of events for rendering a page in ASP.NET. You should be able to google this content for the specific technology you're using (ASP.NET classic, core, MVC, etc.), as changes have been made over the years.

It's particularly important to note that JavaScript code only executes after the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript has reached the browser, and at that point no .NET code can interact with your JavaScript document until a postback occurs or a request is made.

Comment: The main issue for now is i want javascript to run first and then other page load event occur with the method Bindlist.

Comment: That can happen, but it's fairly advanced from where you're at in the learning process. What you would need is a Web service to encapsulate the database call and return the data (written in C#), and JavaScript code to call the web service and retrieve its results, then populate the dropdown with the results.